# How to disallow psql command history duplicates

Tags: postgresql, psql

How to disallow psql command history duplicates?

Is this possible to make psql command history delete all duplicate history commands upon enter of new commands?

Comment: To remove already existing duplicates, on linux one can do `uniq ~/.psql_history ~/.psql_history2; mv ~/.psql_history2 ~/.psql_history`.

Answer (score 11):

You can try setting in the psql prompt

```
\set HISTCONTROL ignoredups
```

you can also set it in a file called `.psqlrc`  in the user home directory
example from my `.psqlrc` file

```
\set HISTCONTROL ignoredups
\set COMP_KEYWORD_CASE upper
```

Answer (score 9):

Set internal variable HISTCONTROL

This is from [PostreSQL 9.4 manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES):

> If this variable is set to **ignorespace**, lines which begin with a space
>   are not entered into the history list. If set to a value of
>   **ignoredups**, lines matching the previous history line are not entered.
>   A value of **ignoreboth** combines the two options. If unset, or if set to
>   any other value than those above, all lines read in interactive mode
>   are saved on the history list.